# Ruby version changing within pre-commit hook

Tags: ruby, rvm, pre-commit

I have RVM installed at 2.6.3, but a pre-commit hook is changing my version back to "system" which is 2.3.7. I am unsure how/ why this is happening, as when I run bundle check outside the pre-commit, it works just fine. This is the log that I am getting, along with my .bash_profile and .bashrc. I have tried using "[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" " in my .bashrc to no success. Much appreciated to anyone who may have some more information on this problem.

> `git commit -m "trying"
>   Using /Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
>   husky > pre-commit (node v8.12.0)
>   Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3
>   husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)`

.bash_profile

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

.bashrc

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it installed, but are you using it?
type:

```
rvm use 2.6.3
```

to use said version of ruby

Comment: Sorry I may not have specified. I am using that version. If you look at the log, it is saying I am using 2.6.3, but then it reverts to 2.3.7

Comment: What does .ruby-version file in project root says?

Comment: 2.6.3, which makes it all the more odd.